# SQL sever constraint data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table Product and Supplier

```
create table Product(
    ProductCode int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null ,
    PurchasePrice numeric(20,3) not null,
    SellPrice numeric(20,3) not null ,
    Type varchar(50) not null,
    SupplierCode int not null 
)
go 

create table Supplier(
    SupplierCode int not null primary key,
    SupplierName varchar(50) not null ,
    Address varchar(50) not null
)
```

I want : A product of Samsung must be television, mobile or tablet.
Help me.

database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibUB8.png)

I want "SupplierCode<>4" because Supplier supply 'food'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with `CHECK` constraint? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You try , i can't

Comment: I think use function but don't know use it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We are here to help, however this is not a code-writing service. Questions here are expected to show some effort of attempting to solve the problem before posting the question. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I try , thank you very much

Comment: How about product of other suppliers, do they also have their own constraint ? We need more info. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do

Comment: example:  No supplier of mobile’s or tablet’s may also supply food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve it this way do something like this in `check` constraint because value depends on different tables.

The most straightforward way would be to create a trigger. This one is after insert. It just deletes rows that are not acceptable. You can experiment and make it `instead of insert` instead

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertProduct  
ON Sales.Product  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS 

    delete from inserted a
    join Supplier b on a.SupplierCode  = b.SupplierCode
    where 
    (b.Supplier = 'Samsung' and a.Type not in ('phone', whatever you need...))
    or (b.Supplier = 'different' and a.Type not in (...))
    --here you put any additional logic for different suppliers

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        RAISERROR ('Couldn't insert into table', 16, 10);  
GO
```

Depending on your case what you can also do is make inserting to the tables available only via stored procedures. Then put the checks in the stored procedure instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to define for each suppliers what kind of products are allowed in your tables.
I think you need a table that defines what producttypes are allowed for what Suppliers, and than you can force this in a trigger or in your client.

First you need a table to define the kind of products

```
table ProductType (ID, Name)
```

this holds info like

```
(1, 'Television'), (2, 'Tablet'), (3, 'Mobi'), (4, 'Food'), and so on...
```

Then replace the field `Type` by ProductTypeID in your `Product` table

Now you can have a table that defines what product types each supplier may have

```
table AllowedProducts (ID, SupplierCode, ProductTypeID)
```

and finally you can check this in your client, or in a trigger if you want to keep this rule in your database
When inserting data you can check if the `ProductTypeID` of the selected `Product` is present in table `AllowedProducts` for the selected ´Supplier` and if not reject the insert.

Comment: oh, i done it. I remove 'Type' in table Product to table 'Supplier' but i want 1 answer is query, Can you help me?

Comment: maybe it would help if you post some sample data

Comment: It will be better to create a new table for the `ProductType` and use that in your `Product` table. As can be seen in the example in my answer

Comment: Could you please provide me the details?

Comment: The details you  need are in my answer

Comment: database : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibUB8.png
I want "SupplierCode<>4" because Supplier supply 'food'.